# How do I remove an application I installed from gitHub?

Tags: uninstall, github

I installed an application from GitHub, namely https://github.com/wavexx/screenkey. I installed it with

```
sudo ./setup.py install
```

Now I want to remove it.

What I tried so far:

```
sudo apt-get remove screenkey
```

Also

```
locate screenkey
```

and then

```
rm -r [the file I found]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this  [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall) you can record python script installed files by `sudo python setup.py --record ~/Desktop/installed_files`, if you have `python-distutils-extra` installed. So do:

```
sudo apt-get install python-distutils-extra
sudo python setup.py --record ~/Desktop/installed_files
xargs -a ~/Desktop/installed_files.txt rm -rvf
```